# How to deserialize an imported java class

Tags: java, scala, jackson, deserialization

I'm with an Scala project and I have to import a Java library as dependency.
I need to make a Snapshot with one of these classes, so I found the problem of serialize and deserialize and object (with Jackson). 
The Java imported class has not public getters and settes, so I had to do this:

```
objMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

With this I was able to save the snapshot. Good!

But, the actual problem is read from disk (deserialize). The error is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of
```

This is because the class is trying to read is an interface.

So, my question is, How can I set which class construct for the interface? Is it possible for an imported class (I have not access to it)?

I want to clarify that in this case I only have a specific class to implement the interface.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You could provide your own implementation of that `interface` to deserialize the object into

Comment: But I need to use the imported class. In fact, this is the only moment that I use the library. This is the reason to add this library to my project.